# Use mapped() in odoo 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

What is mapped and how use this in **odoo 10**?
And how to use mapped and filter in Odoo 10?
example

```
result = sum( order.order_line.filtered(
                lambda r: r.state != "state" ).mapped( "field_name" ) 
)
```

and multiply each value of field1 by other field2 in same table an return all sum.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is fully documented on [Odoo docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.mapped):

> **mapped()**: applies the provided function to each record in the recordset, returns a recordset if the results are recordsets. The provided function can be a string to get field values.

```
# returns a list of names
records.mapped('name')
```

In your code the expression `order.order_line.filtered( lambda r: r.state != "state" ).mapped( "field_name" )` returns a list of `field_name` from `order`. Then `sum` python function do the sum.

Comment: Thank you, for odoo docs i have use that records.mapped(lambda r: r.field1 + r.field2) is working for my.

Answer (score 9):

The filtered will return the recordsets that match the criteria (in your case, the order lines that the state isnt "state").

When you use mapped to the recordset, i will return a list with the field_name for each of the recordset, if the field is a many2one, it will remove duplicates.

Example, you have a recordset with a field called "quantity".

```
record 1: quantity = 5
record 2: quantity = 6
record 3: quantity = 10
```

after the filtered you may have:

```
res = sale.order.line(1,2,3,)
```

when applying mapped:

```
quantities_list = res.mapped('quantity') #[5, 6, 10]
```

so the sum will return 21 if they are float/int.

Hope it helps!